# Change a circle radius programmatically - Canvas

Tags: android, android-animation, android-canvas, android-custom-view

I want to change a circle radius from 0 to 100 programmatically each 500 milliseconds making it like a blinking animation.

Basically, I have two circles drawn having a same center points with different radius. I would like to apply the animation to the circle behind, the othe having the bigger radius.

How do I change the radius of a circle programmatically making it from 0 to 100 then back to 0? I have searched intensivelly on the Internet without result.

Here is how I draw those cercles:

```
private static final int STROKE_WIDTH = 20;
private Paint mInnerCircle, mOutterCircle;
private int centerX, centerY, radius;

public void init(){
        mInnerCircle = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mInnerCircle.setColor(Color.BLUE);
        mInnerCircle.setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL);

        mOutterCircle = new Paint(Paint.ANTI_ALIAS_FLAG);
        mOutterCircle.setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
        mOutterCircle.setStrokeWidth(STROKE_WIDTH);
        mOutterCircle.setColor(Color.parseColor("#33b5e5"));

}

 protected void onDraw(Canvas canvas) {
        super.onDraw(canvas);

            centerX = canvas.getWidth()/ 2;
            centerY = canvas.getHeight()/ 2;
            radius = Math.min(centerX,centerY);

        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius - STROKE_WIDTH / 2, mOutterCircle);
        canvas.drawCircle(centerX, centerY, radius - STROKE_WIDTH, mInnerCircle);

    }
```

The final result should be something like this:

[image]

I've got static circles so far:

[image]

I will appreciate your help.

Comment: Hey I'm sorry to see you deleted the question about finding paths that enclose other-colored stones. There's an approach that ought to work.  Care to un-delete it?

Comment: The question is opened again. Please take a look @Gene

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your Drawable can implement the [AnimatorUpdateListener](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/animation/ValueAnimator.AnimatorUpdateListener) interface:

> Implementors of this interface can add themselves as update listeners
>   to an ValueAnimator instance to receive callbacks on every animation
>   frame, after the current frame's values have been calculated for that
>   ValueAnimator

Then override the onAnimationUpdate() method to handle each frame of the animation.

```
public void onAnimationUpdate(ValueAnimator animator) {

    float radius = (float)animator.getAnimatedValue();

    // Clear canvas and draw next frame

    invalidateSelf();
}
```

And then to start the animation in your `init()` method:

```
public void init() {

    ...

    ValueAnimator valueAnimator = ValueAnimator.ofFloat(START_RADIUS, END_RADIUS);
    valueAnimator.setDuration(DURATION_MILLIS)
    valueAnimator.addUpdateListener(this);
    valueAnimator.setRepeatCount(ValueAnimator.INFINITE);
    valueAnimator.start();

}
```